# Is there an easy way to allow an html document to scroll left and right?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I was making a webpage with a spiderweb style design, meaning content would move out and to the left and right as the user browsed.

I want the user to be able to scroll to the left and to the right as they please.

However, I noticed that it's impossible to scroll to the left while using `direction:ltr`. To fix this, I tried using `direction:rtl` on html and `direction:ltr` on the body. However, when I do this, it becomes unable to scroll to the right. There is the option of putting a `margin-left: var(--left-content-width,0)` modifier on html, but this sacrifices internet explorer 11 compatability, and makes it much harder to keep track of all the content on the left of the viewport. Is there an  easy way to scroll left and right (preferably using just css, but javascript is not out of the question), or are we doomed to constant margin updates forever?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `overflow-x: scroll;`. If anything overflows off of the screen the user can scroll to see it.

Comment: using `overflow: scroll` lets the user scroll to the right, content to the left remains hidden

Comment: @Esdeseserdt1976 I relised there was an error in what my answer was. It now says `overflow-x: scroll;`> You can view the documentation for `overflow` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) and `overflow-x` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x).

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I suppose I wasn't clear enough asking my question. I am placing absolutely positioned elements to the left of the viewport, and trying to scroll to them. I think the problem is not an `overflow`/scroll problem per se, but rather that the content seems entirely omitted from the html- it cannot be programatically scrolled to, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

For the good of people coming across this question, here's the patchwork solution I created in the end.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var hiddenStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("hiddenContent"));
var main = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
var mainStyle = window.getComputedStyle(main);
button.onclick = showHidden;

function showHidden() {
  main.style.marginLeft = hiddenStyle.getPropertyValue("right");
  window.scrollBy(parseInt(hiddenStyle.getPropertyValue("right")), 0);
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 30%;
  height: 3em;
  right: 35%;
  left: 35%;
  top: calc(50% - 3em);
  position: absolute;
}

#hiddenContent {
  left: auto;
  right: 300vw;
  /*example, can be anything including calc() values*/
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="firstContent">
      check this out- if you press
      <button>
          this button
         </button>, more content will appear
    </div>
    <div id="hiddenContent">
      this content is secret. Of course, there is a way for screen readers to see this but it's not needed in the minimum product
    </div>
  </main>
  <script href="example.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

A bit sloppy, but I hope it was a good proof of concept and can help others not take quite as long as I did to solve similar issues.